# Unable to launch Android Emulator: probable trouble with GLES

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using Android Studio. When I try to launch the emulator--with an AVD that is a copied version of the Nexus 5X--using hardware for the graphics, i get this message:

```
    init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
    emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 228MB
    emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
    Hax is enabled
    getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
    Hax ram_size 0x60000000
    Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
    HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
    console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
    emulator: WARNING: The -scale flag is obsolete and will be ignored.
    emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
    Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

And on the app log, it shows this:

```
    Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Cals_Device_API_23 was killed.
```

However, when I run it with 'software' for the graphics, it launches relatively quickly but then never gets past the Android loading screen, where the words android have a gradient moving over them again and again, I think because it is too slow.

So how do I fix it so I can actually use the emulator?

EDIT: on software mode, it says `HAX is working and emulator runs in fast mode`